# .htaccess rewrite not working on localhost for a php application

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was trying to make SEF urls but `.htaccess` isn't working. I have used various code from different websites and nothing works.

The odd thing is that I have Joomla! on my localhost and it works just fine. URL rewriting doesn't work on Joomla! (it doesn't remove the index.php file) but it has SEF URLs like localhost/mywebsite/about-us.

I'm mentioning Joomla! just to let you know that SEF URLs work on my localhost, nothing to do with the web application.

So how can I solve this issue?
The last one I tried was something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: First of all, you are asking alot of questions. Try to ask only one very specific question. After reading your post i got abit worried about what you are doing. Why are you taking over a project that you do not understand at all? Taking a framework project to joomla is not good, unless you have some very specific reasons for doing so. About the index file, check out front controller pattern. The fact that you tried to use Dreamweaver a sign of not being a  experienced webdeveloper. Not to be rude, but maybe you should call in some help and practice some more before taking in such projects.

Comment: First, like i said i'm new to php and i have made the questions more specific to the sef issue. secondly, i'm not taking a framework project to joomla, you misunderstood. i mentioned joomla because i thought u should know that sef urls work on my localhost. About the dreamweaver, yes i was inexperienced when i started the project which was almost a week ago. After 6 days, i was able to get passed DreamWeaver and start writing my own code, and for someone who is on his first big project, 6 days to isn't that bad.

Comment: Make sure your `.htaccess` file doesn't have any invisible unicode characters and check your error logs to see if there are any issues there.

Comment: The edit you made improved the question. I removed my downvote and also added a edit that removed some of the text in top. It really is not needed. Good luck on your project. Btw. add a index.php file, and redirect all request to this. As I mentioned, check "front controller".

Answer (score 1):

Have you set override allow on Apache for your application folder ? If you already have enabled mod_rewrite, then this should be the case.

```
AllowOverride All
```

Try something like `deny from all` in .htaccess file and see whether the file is actually reading by the web server. If you have only `deny from all` in .htaccess file you should get forbidden message for any file. This will help you to know whether your .htaccess file is reading by your web server.